# Flutter: Bloc not navigating to another screen after succesful state update

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, bloc

I'm trying to navigate to another page using blocs / cubits. I have one cubit that successfully navigates to another page upon completion of a method, but for some reason, it doesn't work on another cubit, despite successful state change, and operation done on the method.

```
class WalletCreateDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  const WalletCreateDialog({required this.mnemonic});

  final String mnemonic;

  @override
  _WalletCreateDialogState createState() => _WalletCreateDialogState();
}

class _WalletCreateDialogState extends State<WalletCreateDialog> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    BlocProvider.of<WalletCreateCubit>(context)
        .addCreatedWalletToWalletList(widget.mnemonic);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<WalletCreateCubit, WalletCreateState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is WalletAdded) {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            barrierDismissible: false,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              content: Text(
                'Wallet added! Navigating back to home screen...',
              ),
            ),
          );
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
            WalletOverviewHomeScreen.routeName,
            (route) => false,
          );
        }
      },
      child: AlertDialog(
        content: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.08,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Text("Adding wallet..."),
                    const LoadingIndicator(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In the line of code above, it successfully navigates to `WalletOverviewHomeScreen` upon successful completion of the `addCreatedWalletToWalletList` method.

```
class WalletDeleteDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  const WalletDeleteDialog({required this.walletAddress});

  final String walletAddress;

  @override
  State<WalletDeleteDialog> createState() => _WalletDeleteDialogState();
}

class _WalletDeleteDialogState extends State<WalletDeleteDialog> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    BlocProvider.of<WalletDeleteCubit>(context)
        .deleteWallet(widget.walletAddress);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocListener<WalletDeleteCubit, WalletDeleteState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        if (state is WalletDeleteFinished) {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            barrierDismissible: false,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              content: Text(
                'Wallet deleted! Navigating back to home screen...',
              ),
            ),
          );
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
            WalletOverviewHomeScreen.routeName,
            (route) => false,
          );
        }
      },
      child: AlertDialog(
        content: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.08,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: [
                    Text("Deleting wallet..."),
                    const LoadingIndicator(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

On the other hand, in the line of code above, it doesn't navigate to the same screen after completion of the method. I've already verified that the state has changed in both cubits. Additionally, hot restarting the app would actually show that what was supposed to get deleted, did actually get deleted, thus there's no issue with regards to the implementation of the `deleteWallet` method itself.

How can I navigate to the `WalletOverviewHomeScreen` after completion of the `deleteWallet` method?

For context, below are the state classes for the Cubits.

```
part of 'wallet_create_cubit.dart';

abstract class WalletCreateState extends Equatable {
  const WalletCreateState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class WalletCreateInitial extends WalletCreateState {
  const WalletCreateInitial();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class WalletCreateLoading extends WalletCreateState {
  const WalletCreateLoading();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class WalletCreated extends WalletCreateState {
  final String mnemonic;

  const WalletCreated({required this.mnemonic});

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [mnemonic];
}

class WalletAdding extends WalletCreateState {
  const WalletAdding();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class WalletAdded extends WalletCreateState {
  const WalletAdded();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}
```

```
part of 'wallet_delete_cubit.dart';

abstract class WalletDeleteState extends Equatable {
  const WalletDeleteState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class WalletDeleteInitial extends WalletDeleteState {
  const WalletDeleteInitial();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class WalletDeleteOngoing extends WalletDeleteState {
  const WalletDeleteOngoing();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class WalletDeleteFinished extends WalletDeleteState {
  const WalletDeleteFinished();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}
```

Comment: can you try removing  `Navigator.of(context).pop();` Since you're returning false from callback of `pushNamedAndRemoveUntil`, there is no need to call pop. I beleive that should solve the problem.

Comment: Also check if you're seeng some error in console when using `Navigator.of(context).pop()`

Comment: Same thing, it won't navigate to the screen when running the `deleteWallet` method

Comment: Is your listener getting called? Can you try putting a print statement?

Comment: Turns out, it's not getting called. I don't know why though as the listener for the create cubit is getting called. I've edited the question to include the cubit states.

Comment: Are your previous and new state different? If you're same, listener won't be called.

Comment: No, they're different, the `deleteWallet` method emits 2 states, `WalleteDeleteOngoing` then `WalletDeleteFinished` whenever it's called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the fix was to directly copy the contents of `deleteFromWallet` to the `deleteWallet` function. That is, in the `WalletDeleteCubit` it went from this:

```
Future<void> deleteWallet(String address) async {
    FlutterSecureStorage storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
    emit(WalletDeleteOngoing());
    deleteFromWallet(storage, address);
    debugPrint("Wallet with address: $address is deleted");
    emit(WalletDeleteFinished());
    debugPrint('Emit WalletDeleteFinished');
  }
```

To this:

```
void deleteWallet(String address) async {
    FlutterSecureStorage storage = FlutterSecureStorage();
    emit(WalletDeleteOngoing());
    await storage.delete(
      key: WalletOverviewHomeScreen.walletKey + address,
    );
    debugPrint("Wallet with address: $address is deleted");
    emit(WalletDeleteFinished());
    debugPrint('Emit WalletDeleteFinished');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `Navigator.of(context).pop();`
because you don't need it.  when you use `Navigator.of(context).pushNamedAndRemoveUntil`

Comment: As mentioned in a comment above, it won't navigate to the screen when running the `deleteWallet` method